# Can we make [reorderableColumns]="false" for a specific column with PrimeNg datatable?

Tags: datatable, angular5, primeng

I'm working on a big datatable from PrimeNG and I have one column that I want to be frozen and not allowing the user to move it from its place, it must always be the second column of the table, unlike the other columns.

```html
<p-column field="new" sortable="custom" styleClass="text-center">
        <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-col>
            <nd-table-title [field]="col.field"></nd-table-title>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template let-col let-order="rowData" pTemplate="body"> 
            <div #newAffDiv style="display:inline-block;position:relative">
           <span class="badge" style="margin-right: -10px;border-radius: 18px; border: none; height: 25px;color: white; background-color: #527edb;">New</span>
        </div>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="footer" let-col>
            <nd-table-title [field]="col.field"></nd-table-title>
        </ng-template>
    </p-column>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable the column ordering for particular columns use **[pReorderableColumnDisabled]="true/false"** if the value is true, column gets freeze, if false it can be reordered.

Comment: it isn't a known property of 'p-column'